# Unusual error C2678, C1243(const reference argument not working of struct type)

Tags: c++, struct

I created struct vec3, I added it as a const reference argument but it gives me a strange error that isn't even highlighted. Please help(
I used as a base API that I got, I'm not really sure if it is something I did wrong or if it is something that I need to do with API. It is probably my mistake as the other code I made with a similar structure worked fine.

```
#include <corecrt_math.h>
#include <cassert>
struct Vec4 {
        float x, y, z, w;
        inline Vec4(float x_ = 0.0f, float y_ = 0.0f, float z_ = 0.0f, float w_ = 0.0f) {
            this->x = x_; this->y = y_; this->z = z_; this->w = w_;
        }
        inline Vec4(const Vec4& vec_) { *this = vec_; }
        inline Vec4(const Vec3& vec_, float w_ = 0.0f) : x(vec_.x), y(vec_.y), z(vec_.z), w(w_) {}
        inline ~Vec4() {};
    };
struct Vec3
{
    float x, y, z;
    inline Vec3(float x_ = 0.0f, float y_ = 0.0f, float z_ = 0.0f) {
        this->x = x_; this->y = y_; this->z = z_;
    }
    inline Vec3(const Vec3& vec_) { *this = vec_; }
    inline Vec3(const Vec2& vec_, float z_ = 0.0f) : x(vec_.x), y(vec_.y), z(z_) {}
    inline ~Vec3() {};
    Vec3 operator + (const Vec3& vec_) const;
    Vec3 operator + (float f_) const;
    Vec3 operator * (float f_) const;
    void operator += (const Vec3& vec_);
    void operator += (float f_);
    void operator *= (float f_);
    static friend Vec3 operator + (const Vec2& vec1_, const Vec3& vec2_);
    static friend Vec3 operator - (const Vec2& vec1_, const Vec3& vec2_);
    static friend Vec3 operator * (const float f_, const Vec3& vec_);
    static friend Vec3 operator + (const float f_, const Vec3& vec_);
    Vec3 operator - (const Vec3& vec_) const;
    Vec3 operator - (float f_) const;
    Vec3 operator / (float f_) const;
    void operator -= (const Vec3& vec_);
    void operator -= (float f_);
    void operator /= (float f_);
    bool operator == (const Vec3& vec_) const;
    bool operator != (const Vec3& vec_) const;

    Vec3 operator-() const;
};
struct Vec2 {
    float x, y;
    inline Vec2(float x_ = 0.0f, float y_ = 0.0f) {
        this->x = x_; this->y = y_;
    }
    inline Vec2(const Vec2& vec_) { *this = vec_; }
    inline ~Vec2() {};
    Vec2 operator + (const Vec2& vec_) const;
    Vec2 operator + (float f_) const;
    Vec2 operator * (float f_) const;
    void operator += (const Vec2& vec_);
    void operator += (float f_);
    void operator *= (float f_);
    static friend Vec2 operator * (const float f_, const Vec2& vec_);
    static friend Vec2 operator + (const float f_, const Vec2& vec_);
    Vec2 operator - (const Vec2& vec_) const;
    Vec2 operator - (float f_) const;
    Vec2 operator / (float f_) const;
    void operator -= (const Vec2& vec_);
    void operator -= (float f_);
    void operator /= (float f_);
    bool operator == (const Vec2& vec_) const;
    bool operator != (const Vec2& vec_) const;
    Vec2 operator-() const;
};
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Probably not the cause, but friend operators should not be static.  (see : https://godbolt.org/z/5Wxj5MGj1). And have you included all your header files for Vec2/Vec3 in header file of Vec4?

Comment: Sorry for the bother, I feel so stupid now, I just placed structures in the wrong order. Still thanks for your response)

Comment: Things happen :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for bothering you, I feel so stupid now, I just placed structures in the wrong order. It seems that structures couldn't access info from another. Still thanks for your response)